# On the proof that the product of diagonal matrices is a diagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A [a_{i,j}]$  and $B =[b_{ij}]$   be two diagonal matrices in
>   $M_n(F)$. Let $i \ne j \in \left\{1, \ldots, n \right\}$. Using the
>   product rule, we obtain
>
> $$(AB)_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{ik}b_{kj}$$
>
> We claim that $a_{ik}b_{kj} =0$ for all $k \in \left\{1, \ldots, n
> \right\}$ thus $(AB)_{ij}=0$ for all $i \ne j$ and $AB$ is diagonal. To
>    prove the claim, note that since $i \ne j$ , we have $i \ne k$ or $  
>  k\ne j$. Thus either $a_{ik} = 0$ (since $A$ is diagonal) or $b_{kj} =
>  0$ (since $B$ is diagonal), thus in all cases $a_{ik}b_{kj}=0$ and the
>   claim is proved.

Where does the bit "we have $i \ne k$ or $k\ne j$" come from? I understand that since $i \ne j$, and $k$ and $j$ run over the same set of natural numbers, we also have $i \ne k$. But the "or $k \ne j$" baffles me. I understand that $k \ne j$ implies that we can have $i=k$. But that's from the other direction ($\Longleftarrow).$

Also, when it says $a_{ik}=0$ or $b_{kj}=0$ it's talking about when $i \ne k$ or $k \ne j$ right? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negation of that would be $i=k$ and $k=j$ which would means that $i=j$.

The whole message is it is an off-diagonal entry.

when $i \neq k$,  $a_{ik}=0$, from the definition of diagonal matrix. The off-diagonal entries must be $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Makes sense. Is there a way to see this implication without taking the contrapositive?

Comment: We know that $i$ and $j$ are distinct, so $k$ can't be equal to them simultaneously.

Comment: Wow! Once you put it like that... thanks, again.

Comment: I'm sorry to trouble you again, but would the same proof for upper-triangular matrices work the same way? Would we say $i > j$, then either $i > k$ or $k > j$, thus either $a_{ik} = 0$ or $b_{kj} = 0$, hence $AB$ is upper triangular. The reason I ask this is that the book did it by contradiction, so I wonder whether it's faulty since they used a different method than what worked for the diagonal proof.

Comment: your argument seems fine. It's ok to use different methods.

Answer (score 5):

$A$ is diagonal **iff** if can be written in the form
$A = \sum_k \alpha_k e_k e_k^T$.

If $B=\sum_k \beta_k e_k e_k^T$, then
$AB=\sum_k \alpha_k \beta_k e_k e_k^T$ and hence $AB$ is diagonal.

Comment: Thanks. $\color{white}{Meaning of life = 42}$